# How can I redirect CLIPS input and output while using its API simulating the command line loop?

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, clips, expert-system

I am developing a `WPF` application in `C#` which uses the `CLIPS` expert system engine in some of its parts. I developed a `C++/CLI` wrapper in order to get access to the main APIs of `CLIPS` I need.

What I would like to implement now I the possibility to control the current `CLIPS` data structures as if I was using the command line loop, in order to write directly formatted commands and watch their outcomes.

I was thinking about using a `WPF` `TextBox` control, but any other solution would be good to start with.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download clips_dotnet_010.zip from https://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsrules/files/CLIPS/6.30/. The RouterWPFExample project contains an example of defining a CLIPS router to get input/output from a WPF control. You can set up a text box to grab a command, then use the eval method to execute the command with input/output from/to the WPF control set up for CLIPS I/O. The next version of clips_dotnet will have code demonstrating a WPF control for a full CLIPS command line.